# SQL statement with batch execution to update two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, combobox, sql-update

I have a problem which seems difficult for me, I have a table Category and a table Questions(this table has category_id field with default 0), On my form I can select a category from combobox and  my question to you, how can I Insert/Update to a table a new question to a ready made category?
My code so far Only adds a new question with a 0 as category, not the one from combobox (combobox displays only text)

> String SQL2 = "UPDATE gamequestions SET question_id='gamecategory.category_name =" +jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+" ,gamequestions.category_id = gamecategory.category_id' WHERE question_id='0' ;";
>               stmt.addBatch(SQL2);

This is the updated code

```
"INSERT INTO gamequestions (question_id, category_id, question) SELECT NULL as question_id ,c.category_id, q.question='"+jTextArea1.getText()+"' FROM gamecategory c, gamequestions q WHERE  c.category_name = '"+Combo_click+"' ORDER BY c.category_id LIMIT 1"
```

And I cant figure out how to make jtextarea fill a column question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't figure out what your code is supposed to be doing.

You say you want to either INSERT a new row with a specified value for `category_id` column (something other than a hard coded zero), or you want to UPDATE an existing row to change the value of the `category_id` column.

Let's start with the SQL text that would needs to be sent to the database.

To change an existing row, for example:

```
UPDATE gamequestions q
   SET q.category_id = 2 
 WHERE q.question_id = 42
```

To insert a new row (assuming `question_id` is auto_increment) for example:

```
INSERT INTO gamequestions (question_id, category_id) VALUES (NULL, 2)
```

The value returned from the combobox selection would replace the '2' in the example above.

If your combobox isn't returning the `category_id` value, but is returning the value of some other column from the `gamecategory` table, and you want the SQL statement to do a "lookup" of the `category_id` value from the `gamecategory` table using the `category_name` value, one way to do that is a subquery as the value being assigned to the column...:

```
UPDATE gamequestions q
   SET q.category_id = (SELECT c.category_id 
                          FROM gamecategory c
                         WHERE c.category_name = ?
                         ORDER BY c.category_id
                         LIMIT 1
                       )
 WHERE q.question_id = 42
```

For an `INSERT`, if you only want to insert a row if the `category_name` text matches a row in the `gamecategory` table, you could use SQL like this:

```
INSERT INTO gamequestions (question_id, category_id)
SELECT NULL as question_id
     , c.category_id
  FROM gamecategory c
 WHERE c.category_name = ?
 ORDER BY c.category_id
 LIMIT 1
```

If there is no row in the `gamecategory` table with a `category_name` that matches the specified value (supplied where the `?` is), then no row will be inserted.

If you want to go ahead and insert the row, even if the category_name text doesn't match, and have the `category_id` set to a default value of 0, then something like this, with a subquery in the SELECT list:

```
INSERT INTO gamequestions (question_id, category_id)
SELECT NULL as question_id
     , IFNULL(
         ( SELECT c.category_id
             FROM category c
            WHERE c.category_name = ?
            ORDER BY c.category_id
            LIMIT 1
         )
       ,0) AS category_id
```

The first step is really to get some SQL statements that do what you want.

The second step is to get the SQL text embedded into your application, with the appropriate bind variables/substitutions and avoiding SQL injection vulnerabilities. The second step is hard enough to figure out, without also having to work out the first step at the same time.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

If you are inserting a row into `gamequestions`, we'd expect the value for the `question` column to be supplied in the INSERT statement, it wouldn't be coming from a row in the `gamequestions` table.

The `SELECT` we're running as part of the INSERT is getting the value of `category_id` from the `gamecategory` table; there's no need for a JOIN to the gamequestions table.

I think you want SQL of the form:

```
 INSERT INTO gamequestions
 ( question_id
 , category_id
 , question
 , another_column
 , some_id
 )
 SELECT NULL
      , c.category_id       
      , 'my question text goes here'
      , 'fee fi fo fum'
      , 42
   FROM gamecategory c
  WHERE c.category_name = 'category name text goes here'
  ORDER BY c.category_id
  LIMIT 1
```

That will insert a new row, with the value of

- `some_id` set to integer value of 42
- `another_column` set to a string value of `'fee fi fo fum'`
- `question` set to a string value of `'my question text goes here'`
- `category_id` set to a value retrieved from the `gamecategory` table

Ideally, you wouldn't need to do a lookup of the category_id from the database at all; ideally, your combo box would display the `category_name`, but return a value of `category_id`, so you could just directly insert that:

```
 INSERT INTO gamequestions
 ( question_id
 , category_id
 , question
 , another_column
 , some_id
 ) VALUES
 ( NULL
 , 5
 , 'my question text goes here'
 , 'fee fi fo fum'
 , 42
 )
```

without having to run a SELECT on the insert.

Ideally, instead of returning the `category_name` text as a value, the combo box would return the appropriate `category_id` value. Put the "lookup" into the drop down

For example, represent the `gamecategory` table contents:

```
id  category_name
--  ---------------
 0  Uncategorized
 1  Action-Adventure
 2  Adventure
 3  Aerial Combat
 4  Fighting
 5  First Person Shooter
 6  Fitness
```

In an HTML combobox like this:

```
 <select name=category_id>
 <option value='0' selected>Uncategorized</option>
 <option value='1'>Action-Adventure      </option>
 <option value='2'>Adventure             </option>
 <option value='3'>Aerial Combat         </option>
 <option value='4'>Fighting              </option>
 <option value='5'>First Person Shooter  </option>
 <option value='6'>Fitness               </option>
 </select>
```

To get the value from the combobox in javascript, for example:

```
$('select[name="category_id"]').val();
```

**FOLLOWUP**

The `question_id` column could be omitted from the `INSERT` statement, then we wouldn't need to supply the `NULL` value for it.

```
 INSERT INTO gamequestions (category_id, question, another_column)
 VALUES (5, 'my question text goes here', 'fee fi fo fum');
```

-or-

```
 INSERT INTO gamequestions (category_id, question, another_column)
 SELECT 5, 'my question text goes here', 'fee fi fo fum'
```

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q:** what if I was to insert multiple rows into question column while using INSERT INTO gamequestions, so I can have i.e. 3 textfields each containing different question but each going to same game category INSERT INTO gamequestions ( question_id , category_id , question , another_column , some_id ) VALUES ( NULL , 5 , 'my question text goes here' , 'fee fi fo fum' , 42 )

**A:** Using the VALUES clause, you can do a multi-row insert (a very powerful and non-standard extension provided by MySQL).

The SQL that you would send to the database would need to look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO gamequestions (category_id,question,another_column,some_id)
VALUES 
 (5, 'my question text goes here'  , 'fee fi fo fum'     , 42)
,(5, 'another question to be added', 'i smell the blood' , 84)
,(5, 'and this is a third row'     , 'of an englishman'  , 17)
```

(I've omitted the question_id column, we'll let that be assigned the DEFAULT NULL value and the real value will be assigned by AUTO_INCREMENT. Note the column is still being "inserted" along with the rest of the row, we're just giving an incomplete list of columns, and letting MySQL assign default values for the columns we don't specify.)

The real "trick" here is that we have three rows, three sets of values. The set of values for each row is enclosed in parens, just like in the single row insert. But MySQL allows us to tack on a comma, and another set of values for another row.

The category_id assigned on each row has to be individually supplied for each row, it can be the same value as previous rows, or entirely different, doesn't make any difference. (The only difference the values make is whether MySQL is going to throw an error, because of a constraint violation, a problem with converting datatypes, something like that.)

(MySQL ignores all that spacing, I just added the spacing to make it more readable.)

Comment: You sir are my hero, this is great, I have used your first insert method however I cant figure out where I would insert the question text, If you could please refer back to my code where you will find an update of it. thanks

Comment: can you also tell me why do you always start SELECT statement with NULL?

Comment: I don't always start a SELECT with NULL; I was assuming that the `question_id` column was AUTO_INCREMENT, so inserting a NULL value is one way to get a value automatically assigned. That NULL isn't really "first", it's just in the position the corresponds with the position of `question_id` in the column list. That column could be omitted from the INSERT statement, then the corresponding NULL value wouldn't need to be supplied.

Comment: I thought so, it all works not and yes the ID column was auto increment, I cant thank you enough

Comment: this is wonderful! one more question, what if I was to insert multiple rows into question column while using INSERT INTO gamequestions, so I can have i.e. 3 textfields each containing different question but each going to same game category
 INSERT INTO gamequestions
 ( question_id
 , category_id
 , question
 , another_column
 , some_id
 ) VALUES
 ( NULL
 , 5
 , 'my question text goes here'
 , 'fee fi fo fum'
 , 42
 )

Comment: I added yet another followup. I hope you find the information I added to this answer helpful, in your pursuit to write better software. I'm going to throw out a mention of one other very important topic.  **SQL Injection** vulnerabilities. If you construct SQL text which contains user supplied data which is NOT verified to be "safe", there's a potential for someone to "hack" your application and database. Consider what would happen if someone carelessly (or carefully) entered specific text into a textarea ala Little Bobby Tables [http://xkcd.com/327/](http://xkcd.com/327/)